# Prove the inequality for $x>y>0$:$ x\ln(x) + y\ln(y) >(x+y)\ln\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to solve it by differentiate both side and find the first derivatives are the same, then to use Roll's theorem twice. However,I cannot continue from that.

Comment: This can be shown using Jensen's inequality applied to the convex function $x \log x$.

Answer (score 2):

We know the jensen's inequality $\frac{f(x)+f(y)}2>f(\frac{x+y}{2})$ if $f(x)$ is strictly convex in $[x, y]$. Here $f(x)=x \ln{x}$

$\implies f'(x)= 1+\ln{x}$

$\implies f''(x)= 1/x \implies f''(x)>0$  if  $x>0 $

Thus $f$ is strictly convex in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Thus, we have $\frac{x\ln{x}+y\ln{y}}2>\frac{x+y}2\ln{\frac{x+y}{2}}$

The result follows immediately.

Comment: how can we know f(x)+f(y)/2>f(x+y/2) from jensen's inequality? if it is derived from setting t= 1/2?

Comment: Jensen's inequality says $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)\geq f(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)$ if $f''(x)\geq 0$. But here since $f''(x)> 0$ thus strict inequality prevails. What is 't'?

Comment: in this case ,$n=2$. what's t?